# How can open LinkedIn Comapny Url in iPhone app programmatically?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I want open LinkedIn company Url from my iPhone app to LinkedIn app by using programmatically. I am use following code but not working please help me ....

```
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"linkedin://company/COMPANY_ID"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
```

Comment: Is the any one who can help me on this.

Comment: Any one is there who resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reaplce your code like this:

```
     NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.linkedin.com/your_companyName/Your_COMPANY_ID"];//if dyanmic then pass it as a parameter.

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works fine with the current linkedIn App as of date of posting.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"linkedin://company/%@", companyID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This will open the linkedIn app, prompting for login if not already and show the company page for the given companyID.

Comment: Just reconfirmed this is working for me. Using the linkedIn app version 8.8.1 on an iOS 8.3 device.  You need to use the numeric company ID.  You should be able to confirm you have the correct number by going to https://www.linkedin.com/company/<companyID> and seeing if it displays the company profile page.

Comment: You can find the companyID to use by viewing the source of the profile page and searching for companyId=

Comment: `companyId` cannot be found on 2023

Answer (score 0):

You misuse the Format, I think what you wanted it to do should be done like this:

```
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"linkedin://%@/%@", company, COMPANY_ID];
```

assuming that company and COMPANY_ID are some strings you declared elsewhere.

Comment: I am using any of the company id like 123456 in place of "COMAPNY_ID". But its not working for company. i.e. string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"linkedin://company/xxxxxxx"]; here xxxxxxx is the company id.

Comment: string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"linkedin://company/%@", COMPANY_ID];

Try this.

Comment: Tried but still having same problem.

Comment: I don't really know how the linkedin:// urls are constructed. Do you have an example url that you checked that it actually works?

Comment: I open profile by using following url format and its working.    "linkedin://profile/{id}"

Comment: Then the line should be:
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"linkedin://profile/%@", COMPANY_ID];

Comment: Did any of this actually work ? I'm only managing to open the app but I don't get redirected to the company page.

Answer (score 0):

```
linkedin://you
linkedin://profile/[profile id]
linkedin://group/[group id]
```

See [How can I open Linkedin application from my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101831/how-can-i-open-linkedin-application-from-my-android-app)