# What are different url schemes for iOS LinkedIn app?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, url-scheme

I'm trying to open different content from my app into LinkedIn App.

To open profile I'm using linkedin://profile/{id} and it works. I'm looking for the other schemes in order to open:

- An update
- Company page
- Group page

if you know any other url it would be much appreciated. 
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems it is not possible to link to updates, company pages or group pages using the linkedin:// scheme.

Linking to company pages was discussed here a while ago and it doesn't seem to have change sinced then: [How can open LinkedIn Comapny Url in iPhone app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466385/how-can-open-linkedin-comapny-url-in-iphone-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a scheme that would successfully open the app to a group page. However, For groups I was able to use this format (after much trial and error!): "https://www.linkedin.com/groups/YOUR_GROUP_NUMBER"   This still opens up the app even though it's not a scheme.

Also, in your plist file make sure you add the key "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes", select "Array" as the type, and then add "linkedin" as an item in the array.