# LinkedIn open url company in iOS (URL Scheme)

Tags: ios, xcode, url, linkedin-api

I need to open in the *LinkedIn* app a company url from my iOS app in Swift. I have tried to do that with `URL Scheme`, but I haven't achieved it.

This code open the LinkedIn app, but not in the url I need:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "linkedin://profile/xxx_id_company_xxx")!)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

In your info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes add

```
<string>linkedin</string>, then in your code just add

let webURL = URL(string: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/yourName-yourLastName-yourID/")!

let appURL = URL(string: "linkedin://profile/yourName-yourLastName-yourID")!

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(appURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.open(webURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the correct format is "linkedin://companyName/companyId"

See this SO question: [How can open LinkedIn Comapny Url in iPhone app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466385)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad copy/paste and thank you for the editing.

Comment: No worries, I however failed to do it correctly as I thought it would be enough do just delete the trailing /edit. Sorry about that :)

Comment: I have already tried with this format, but it only opens LinkedIn app, without opening the company profile :(

Answer (score 0):

This linkedin company url scheme is working for me

- linkedin://company?id={company-id}

This objective c code trys to open linkedin company page in linkedin app and fall backs to a modal webview presenting company web page.

```
/* try to open linkedin app with company url */
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://company?id=2589010"]]) {
    /* Unable to open linked app, present web page with url @"https://www.linkedin.com/company/sesli-sozluk" */
    ...
}
```

You can find your "company id" in the source code of your company page on linkedin. Search for "company-id" or "companyId", it is in a hidden input field.