# How do I open the LinkedIn app from my app without knowing the profile ID?

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api, social-networking

I'm trying to apply the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885121/3165621), but I only have the URL of the linkedIn profile, not the ID. This code always ends up o

```
String username = "bill-johnson"; // this is inferred from the full URL

public void toLinkedIn(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("linkedin://" + username));
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
                // fall back on the full URL, which I also know.
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(LINKEDIN_URL));
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn's Android SDK provides a function to "deep link" to profiles directly within the official LinkedIn app.  I would suggest you check it out:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk#deeplink